# ANTLR4: Match backslash in C# target

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have got the following lexer rule:

```
ORDERID: [a-zA-Z0-9\-_:;\./]+;
```

and the following parser rule:

```
orderIdFilter: 'OrderId' 'IN' '"'ORDERID(','ORDERID)*'"';
```

I don't understand how, but it matches this input:

```
"OrderId IN \"08\\04\\07\""
```

I am not sure how that is the case. Why am I not getting an "InputMismatch" exception?

Comment: It doesn't match in my tests. Is "OrderId IN \"08\\04\\07\"" the exact input ? Can you provide more code/context ?